# Excel use of indirect

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to reference another worksheet but can not get the indirect to work.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((MATCH(AD10,A1:A160,0))+ROW(Page!A1)-1,COLUMN(Page!A1),4))
```

It is only returning the search result for the page not for the page requested.

It needs to return the data in the cell not the location.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
=INDEX(Page!A:A,MATCH(AD10,A1:A160,0)+ROW(1:1)-1)
```

Comment: That is good, but I also want to move the row and column to other cells. And I want the row to be set by a changing variable number in another cell

Answer (score 1):

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(Page!A1:A160,MATCH(AD10,Page!A1:A160,0)), AE10+1, 1)
```

This allowed me to move the row automatically and shift the column to gather that rows information....Thanks for the help.